# Angularjs service unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, service, karma-runner

I created this service for mocking the localStorage

```
var myModule = angular.module('mockLocalStorageModule', []);
myModule.factory('serviceMockLocalStorage', function() {
  var mock = (function () {
var store = {};
return {
  getItem: function (key) {
    return store[key];
  },
  setItem: function (key, value) {
    store[key] = value.toString();
  },
  clear: function () {
    store = {};
  },
  removeItem: function (key) {
    delete store[key];
  }
};
})();
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {value: mock, enumerable: true, writable: true, configurable: true});

});
```

and my karma test contains this

```
beforeEach(module('mockLocalStorageModule'));
```

but the service is not used, the test is using the real localStorage. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Karma is not a testing framework.  It is a test runner that is used to run your unit tests written with a unit testing framework, like Jasmine or Mocha.  Do you know which framework you are using?  It's probably one of those.  Could you include more of your test where you instantiate the mocked service?

Answer (score 0):

In your Unit Test you're going to need to do something like this to mock out the original LocalStorage

```
angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$LocalStorage', mockLocalStorage);
    });
```